# JS : Drying up jQuery script - checkbox values to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

I have a script that puts checkbox values into a (hidden) input field.

Can see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/6DpmK/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            var $checkboxes = jQuery(".o99_remove_check");
            $checkboxes.on('change', function() {
                var ids = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
                    return this.value;
                }).get().join(' | ');
                jQuery('#o99_brsa_settingsbrsa_remove_menu_list').val(ids);
            });


        });
```

The problem is : How can I repeat this over multiple iterations (like the 2 in the example) but ***without*** repeating myself with the jQuery (the markup is generated by php, so it is not problem)

Right now, I just repeat the whole script while incrementing the checkbox class to `o99_remove_check2` and the input id to `o99_brsa_settingsbrsa_remove_menu_list2`, but my poor js skills does not allow me to think of a solution to make it in a single script .

Whatever else i tried just confused the script , sending one checkbox list value to another input field, or even updating all of them together ( I tried with 5 instances. )

**Edit I** after comments / respons

I would prefer a solution where I can attribute the same class to all of the checkboxes..

Comment: "Drying up"? Does it mean "Trying out"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap ur options in a div with a class name called 'wrapper'.This will hold the options and the hidden text box.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>FIELD SET 1</p>
    <input class="checkbox o99_remove_check" type="checkbox" value="Option1" name="brsa-remove-SubMenu-general.php">Option1
    <br>
    <input class="checkbox o99_remove_check" type="checkbox" value="Option2" name="brsa-remove-SubMenu-writing.php">Option2
    <br>
    <input class="checkbox o99_remove_check" type="checkbox" value="Option3" name="brsa-remove-SubMenu-reading.php">Option3
    <br>
    <input type="text" value="" name="o99_brsa_settings[brsa_remove_menu_list]" id="o99_brsa_settingsbrsa_remove_menu_list_big" class="regular-text" disabled="true">
    <label for="o99_brsa_settingsbrsa_remove_menu_list_big" class="description">
        <br>this will actually be hiiden field</label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Have a script that will attach a common event for all ur checkbox as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 var $checkboxes = jQuery(".wrapper .checkbox");
    $checkboxes.on('change', function () {
        var ids = jQuery(this).parent().find('.checkbox').filter(':checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(' | ');
        jQuery(this).parent().find('.regular-text').val(ids)

    });
});
```

This script will find the parent of the selected checkbox group and will find the HiddenTextBox (identified by 'classname regular-text') an display the value as u desire.
Also any no o iterations,u need no chage on ur script.Just add the HTML fragment (make sure u give the correct className)...Hope this helps...
for JsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/GUZaD/9/

Comment: Thanks, a lot . It works great . The reason why I want to "automate" it more (not using the same class ) is that I use those classes also for other scripts, and putting different classes just complicate things even more . Thanks again .can learn a lot from your script .

Answer (score 2):

If there is a number at the end of each class, you can something like this:

```
jQuery("[class^='o99_remove_check']").change(function() {
    var class = $(this).attr("class");
    var classNum = class.substr(class.length - 1); //Number at the end of each class

    var ids = $(".o99_remove_check"+classNum).filter(':checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(' | ');

    jQuery('#o99_brsa_settingsbrsa_remove_menu_list'+classNum).val(ids);
});
```

Comment: thanks, That might work for me , But Can there be a solution where also the class would be identical ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking? Keep the same class for each set of checkbox's?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the checkbox selector and hidden field selector variables of a function you can then call that function twice.

http://jsfiddle.net/SPuNy/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var initCheckboxList = function (checkboxSelector, hiddenInputSelector) {
        var $checkboxes = jQuery(checkboxSelector);
        $checkboxes.on('change', function () {
            var ids = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(' | ');
            jQuery(hiddenInputSelector).val(ids);
        });
    }

    initCheckboxList('.o99_remove_check', '#o99_brsa_settingsbrsa_remove_menu_list_big');
    initCheckboxList('.o99_remove_check2', '#o99_brsa_settingsbrsa_remove_menu_list2');
});
```